# Regular expression : create a pattern that matches with dynamic content

Tags: android, regex

I develop a mobile Android application that reads incoming SMS and sends it to the server. The server in turn reads the content of the received SMS and retrieves key information.

The message format is as follows:

> Transaction ID: **CI180212.0827.B41246**: You have received **2500.0000** USD from XXX, XXX XXX. your new balance is 27790.7000 USD.

What interests me is the amount, in this example **2500.0000** USD. But the problem is that the transaction ID (**CI180212.0827.B41246**) is dynamic and may have more characters than the previous one, so I can not put in place an effective pattern to handle that.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://regex101.com/r/xKR9J1/2), Or just first `USD `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(?<= )[\d\.]+`

(?<= ) - before that have space
[\d.]+ - any digit with `.`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/xKR9J1/2/)